# Looping over the result in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-cursor

Example table

```
id  emplrcd effdt   country visited
------------------------------------
112233  0   10/9/2018   US
112233  1   10/10/2018  IND
112233  1   10/11/2018  BAN
112233  1   10/12/2018  PAK
112233  0   10/13/2018  US
112233  2   10/14/2018  IND
112233  2   10/16/2018  THA
112233  2   10/17/2018  SIN
112233  0   10/18/2018  US

223344  0   10/9/2018   US
223344  1   10/10/2018  IND
223344  1   10/11/2018  BAN
223344  1   10/12/2018  PAK
223344  0   10/13/2018  US
223344  2   10/14/2018  IND
```

I want to loop over certain result set from the query, e.g id 112233 is from US, between two US country code where the country code represents the country he visited.

`count(*)` where country visited = US --> 3

Now I want to iterate over my result 3 times getting all the intermediate dates he went outside. Can this be done in a single SQL query or do I need something like cursor to do this?

Result for the above cursor or query should return the following rows

```
112233  1   10/10/2018  IND
112233  1   10/11/2018  BAN
112233  1   10/12/2018  PAK
112233  2   10/14/2018  IND
112233  2   10/16/2018  THA
112233  2   10/17/2018  SIN

223344  1   10/10/2018  IND
223344  1   10/11/2018  BAN
223344  1   10/12/2018  PAK
```

Comment: can you post what the expected results would be?

Comment: Your results look like you just want the data set without any of the rows where US is the country visited.... is that correct?

Comment: @RyanB., not quite. The dates have to be bounded by a US visit. Note the absence of `10/14/2018  IND` in the second data set.

Comment: @RyanB., Eric is right i want the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(case when t.country = 'US' then t.effdt end) over (partition by t.id) as us_min_effdt,
             max(case when t.country = 'US' then t.effdt end) over (partition by t.id) as us_max_effdt
      from t
     ) t
where country <> 'US' and
      effdt >= us_min_effdt and efft < us_max_effdt;
```

Comment: slick, as usual

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using a CTE to set up your boundry conditions.

```
-------------------------
-- TEST SCHEMA

create table #datatable (id varchar(6), emplrcd int, effdt date, [country visited] varchar (3))

insert into #datatable values

('112233',0,'10/9/2018 ','US '),
('112233',1,'10/10/2018','IND'),
('112233',1,'10/11/2018','BAN'),
('112233',1,'10/12/2018','PAK'),
('112233',0,'10/13/2018','US '),
('112233',2,'10/14/2018','IND'),
('112233',2,'10/16/2018','THA'),
('112233',2,'10/17/2018','SIN'),
('112233',0,'10/18/2018','US '),
('223344',0,'10/9/2018 ','US '),
('223344',1,'10/10/2018','IND'),
('223344',1,'10/11/2018','BAN'),
('223344',1,'10/12/2018','PAK'),
('223344',0,'10/13/2018','US '),
('223344',2,'10/14/2018','IND')

-------------------------
-- QUERY

; WITH boundryDate AS 
(
    SELECT 
        id
         ,min (effdt) mindate
         , max(effdt) maxdate

     FROM
        #datatable
     WHERE
        [country visited] = 'US'
     GROUP BY
        id
)

SELECT
    *
FROM
    #datatable dt

    JOIN boundryDate bd
        on dt.id = bd.id
        and dt.effdt between bd.mindate and bd.maxdate
WHERE
    [country visited] <> 'US'
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the EXISTS() function to return all rows that are not "US", and where there EXISTS() a "US" row before, and there EXISTS() a "US" row after.

Comment: for the 2nd id 223344, if you see `223344  2   10/14/2018  IND`  doesnt fall under two US country code. So this should not come.

Comment: And it won't, since there doesn't exist a correlated "US" row after `223344 2 10/14/2018 IND`.   My solution will work if you try it.